# AWS EC2 RDS R Shiny - Could not find function DBI::dbFetch()

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, amazon-rds

I have an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and an AWS RDS MySQL instance. I have connected the two so that my Ubuntu instance can interface with my MySQL database. I have tested the connection and it works. The reason I have done this is so that I can publish a Shiny app for querying my database.

I have installed the prerequisite packages, `DBI` and `RMySQL` on my EC2 instance and have called them appropriately in the script. However, I get the error message `could not find function "dbFetch"` when running the app.

I know something is weird about this because the same script runs on my local. First thing I did was go into my instance's version of R to test out the function. I got the same error message. So I downloaded the DBI package from Github after which the function worked in its R. However, even after rebooting the server, my script returns the same error.

My server.app looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)

server <- function(input, output) {
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                  dbname = "isi490",
                  host = "isi490.cse8ifih4f0f.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
                  port = 3306,
                  user = "user",
                  password = "password")
  output$table <- renderTable({
    res <- dbSendQuery(db, input$query)
    dbFetch(res)
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to install packages globally (usually in `/usr/lib/R/library` on linux servers) in order to make them work with `shiny-server`. Just using `install.packages("DBI")` will install them locally (somewhere in `~/R/`) so `shiny-server` can't access them. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Gregor. You're right about that, I thought this might be the issue. I actually did install them globally and I'm still getting it however.